# Is Chrome microphone supposed to be not working if there is no Internet Connection?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using a JS plug-in called Annyang, a Speech Recognition tool and of course it requires a working mic. Everything works just fine with normal Internet connection, but when I disable my Internet Connection, the plug in won't work at any level. (and I did check the plug-in's JS file and found nothing that needs any Internet Connection to be functioned.

Is Chrome microphone supposed to be not working if there is no Internet Connection ? Or something is wrong with the plug-in..?

Thanks a lot for reading this question. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the microphone that needs internet connection,
it's google's implementation of speech-recognition API, which sends the recorded data to their server to get the computed STT.

Nothing you can do on your side, not an Annyang bug either.